# Problem with hello world tutorial in dcoder

Tags: java

New to coding. Searched following query to no avail.

I'm using Dcoder IDE and trying the Hello World tutorial.

The following error message occurs when I try to output my code.

```
source_file.java:1: error: class HelloWorld1 is public, 
should be declared in a file named HelloWorld1.java
public class HelloWorld1
       ^
1 error
```

My code is as follows

```
public class HelloWorld1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The file is saved as HelloWorld1.java

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is also an old file `source_file.java`

Comment: What is your filename? It should be HelloWorld1.java

Comment: I am wondering why this post got 1 vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is saved as `source_file.java`. In order for your code to compile, it must be named `HelloWorld1.java`.

To improve the readability of your code it is often a good practice to indent, like this:

```
public class HelloWorld1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the file is saved as HelloWorld1.java? Because in the output you posted it reads it as "source_file.java".

Comment: In older version of Dcoder to compile the code, Dcoder copies it to a new file source_file.java, to solve your issue either remove public keyword from your class name, that should make it work or use latest version and use new project support feature. This also allows writing multiple java files, link them and has a .dcoder_run file to specify your compile and run commands. Make sure you edit these commands in case you change default filename and classname.